# Developer console activates by itself

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-security

Over the last day, whenever a friend opens gmail in any installed browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) on her Win 10 machine, the developer console opens automatically.

Why might this be and how to stop it?

Googling, it doesn't look like it is possible to do this via Javascript.  So a malicious proxy ought not be able to make it happen.  Any ideas?

Maybe a malicious Windows program sending keystrokes to the browser?

Comment: Have you satisfactorily ruled out the user as the cause? Does it happen if someone else operates the keyboard/mouse in her stead?

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/12212504/1380370 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having installed https://github.com/Code52/carnac to show keystrokes onscreen, I can now see that the F12 key is sporadically becoming sticky.

My working hypothesis is that this is a physical keyboard issue, not malware.